# Concatenating a struct containing variable sized data in one char*

Tags: c, struct, printf

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct message
{
    char* dchatver;
    int contype;
    int conlen;
    char* context;
} message_t;
```

and I need a function that gets a pointer to a filled `message_t`, which will write the `message_t` to a file descriptor.  A message_t could contain `dchatver = "DCHAT:1.0"; contype = 3; conlen = 6; context = "hello";` And I'd like to concatenate it into one `char[totallength]` looking like "`DCHAT:1.0\n3\n6\nhello\n`"

My question is how do I concatenate `dchatver`, `contype`, `conlen` and `context` to one `char*`, in order to use it for write? I've considered using `snprintf`, but I don't know how to determine the length of the given `message_t`.

Comment: Can you show some examples of what the output will look like given a sample message_t? How do you want to represent the end of `dchatver` so that you know where `contype` starts?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough haccks.. 
A message_t could contain for instance `dchatver = "DCHAT:1.0"; contype = 3; conlen = 6; context = "hello";`
And I'd like to concatenate it into one char[totallength].. looking like `"DCHAT:1.0\n3\n6\nhello\n"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void WriteMessage(int fd, message_t *message)
   {
   char *writeBuf=NULL;
   size_t writeBufSize;

   /* Determine the size of the output string. */
   writeBufSize = 1 + snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s\n%d\n%d\n%s\n",
         message->dchatver,
         message->contype,
         message->conlen,
         message->context
         );

   /* Allocate memory for the string */
   writeBuf = malloc(writeBufSize);

   /* Initialize the string. */
   snprintf(writeBuf, writeBufSize, "%s\n%d\n%d\n%s\n",
         message->dchatver,
         message->contype,
         message->conlen,
         message->context
         );

   /* write the record */
   write(fd, writeBuf, writeBufSize - 1);

   free(writeBuf);

   return;
   }
```

Comment: this is it! I wouldn't have come to the idea using the return value of snprintf to determine the lenght!
But if I write the writeBuf in this function, I wouldn't need to malloc the buffer, correct?

Comment: @apoc, __write()__ does not allow a _formatString_, only a buffer.  You will probably still have to use __malloc()__ in order to produce a formatted string for __write()__.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the length of `dchatver` and `context` using `strlen`.  To find the length of `contype` and `conlen` is more difficult but you can take a short cut.  Instead of finding the length of those particular fields, you can calculate their maximum length with this:

```
#include <limits.h>

#define INT_STR_LEN_UPPER_BOUND (sizeof (int) * CHAR_BIT * 3.4)
```

And so you can allocate this much space for each `int` field, pass this to `snprintf` and then use `strlen` on that to get the actual length of the whole string.  Like this:

```
size_t s = strlen (msg->dchatver) + strlen (msg->context) + 
    sizeof (int) * 54.4 + 4;
char *out = calloc (s, sizeof *out);
snprintf (out, s, "%s %d %d %s", msg->dchatver, msg->contype, 
          msg->conlen, msg->context);
```

Comment: I was analyzing `INT_STR_LEN_UPPER_BOUND` and thought it would underestimate in some situations.  However, I realized it's actually overallocating by _insane_ margins.  I assure you that a 32bit integer won't take 102 bytes.  I think you meant to `/ 3.3 + 1` instead of `* 3.4` (which I found safe with any vaguely reasonable numbers for `CHAR_BIT` and `sizeof(int)`, though I didn't _prove_ anything)  You're probably already aware, but using `log(10) ~ 3.32192809489` would decrease overhead slightly sometimes.

Comment: Also, I think `sizeof(int)*54.4` should be `1+sizeof(int)*2.40823996531`.  (where that magic number is `log(256,10)`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting this to mean you want to print the variable values to the screen.

If you are sure that each char* is properly null-terminated, you can just use sprintf() rather than snprintf().

For example, this will print out each variable on a new line, with strings encapsulated in quotes:

```
char buf[256]; // make sure this buffer is large enough
message_t msg;

//
// assuming the variable 'msg' gets filled in here
//

sprintf(buf, "dchatver = \"%s\"\ncontype = %d\nconlen = %d\ncontext = \"%s\"\n", 
   msg.dchatver, 
   msg.contype, 
   msg.conlen, 
   msg.context);

// print the string to console, or do other stuff
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

Comment: Your implementation has a massive hole, exposing it to a buffer overflow attack.  Also, if even in normal operation the `msg.dchatver` field is longer than 256 bytes, it will break the program.

Comment: this is exactly what I had in mind, but the problem I still have is how to determine the buf length, since I want it just being the length of the given data of the message_t..

Comment: As @randomusername said, you'll have to be confident the buffer size is correct if you take the above approach exactly.  In some cases, it is known that certain strings will be N characters or less, so you can select an appropriate bound.

Comment: I understand. For the strings its quite easy to determine the length, then I can just add the number of "\n"s used in the sprintf. But how do I know, how much space the two int's contype and conlen will take up?

Comment: Similar to a string, if you know that integers will be bounded, you can estimate the number of characters it will take to print.  For example, if 'conlen' will always be [0, 99], then it will take at most 2 characters to print.  @randomusername's valid concern is that you make such assumptions, but then enter a value like 999 for 'conlen'.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that can convert a `message_t` to a string in the format that you want to use.

```
char* messageToString(message_t m)
{
   char buffer1[50]; // If your numbers can occupy more than 50 spaces, 
   char buffer2[50]; // these will have to be updated.
   char* ret = NULL;
   size_t len = 0;

   sprintf(buffer1, "\n%d", m.contype);
   sprintf(buffer2, "\n%d\n", m.conlen);
   len = strlen(m.dchatver) + strlen(buffer1) + strlen(buffer2) + strlen(m.context);
   ret = malloc(len+2); // One extra for the newline. One extra for the null

   strcpy(ret, m.dchatver);
   strcat(ret, buffer1);
   strcat(ret, buffer2);
   strcat(ret, m.context);
   strcat(ret, "\n");

   return ret;
}
```

Make sure you call `free` on the returned value to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: this would work quite well! but how do I determine the exact buffer size for the two int values? I wouldn't want to just use a "big enough" buffer..

Comment: @apoc: If you have a 32bit integer, then 11 bytes (plus one for NULL) is big enough for an integer in base 10.  10 bytes if it's always positive.  R Sahu here is providing 50, which is overkill, but harmless.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that you don't necessarily need to know the length of the formatted message string, all you need is an upper bound.  And you know the formatted message will never be longer than `strlen(dchatver)` + 10 (for the contype) + 10 (for the conlen) + conlen (for the context) + 3 (for the '\n's). (conlen apperently includes space for the trailing null, so we don't necessarily have to add one for that, but it might be good to, just in case.)

The magic number 10 assumes that your `int` type is 32 bits, and always positive, if those aren't safe assumptions, you have to do a bit more math.

I like to do this for flexibility. (My C is rusty so there may be syntactical errors here)

```
//this allows you to format to preallocated buffers, saving you
//allocation overhead, and possibly copy overhead
int printf_message(char* buffer, int len, message_t* msg) 
{
    assert(msg->conlen == strlen(msg->context)+1); //just in case
    int r = snprintf(buffer, len, "%s\n%d\n%d\n%s\n",
            msg->dchatver, msg->contype, msg->conlen,  msg->context);
    return r;
}

//this is slightly easier to use, with a small potential overhead
//free the return pointer with "free" when you're done
char* get_formatted_message(message_t* msg) 
{ 
    //contype is a 32bit positive integer, and therefore a maximum of 10 digits 
    //conlen is a 32bit positive integer, and therefore a maximum of 10 digits
    //we need 3 '\n's, and one '\0'.
    int len = strlen(msg->dchatver) + conlen + 24;
    char* buffer = malloc(len);
    if (buffer) 
    {
        printf_message(buffer, len, msg);
    }
    return buffer;
}
```